# javascript executed in the wrong order

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, chromium

In Chrome console, it seems the 2nd line executes before the 1st line. Why?

```
function fn(obj){
    console.log(obj);
    obj.a = 1;
}

fn({b:1}); // prints {a:1, b:1} in console! WHAT!!!
fn({});    // prints {}. OMG. WHAT. This is inconsistent with above behaviour!
```

This DOESN'T happen in Edge console.

Comment: Open the empty object it will show you {a:1}. I have tried it in google chrome console. As you are copying by reference I guess when you are opening the object its reading from the reference again and at that moment obj.a=1 is already executed so you are seeing the later value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a <s>bug</s> feature of the Chrome devtools console. For example if you run this code snippet, you will get

```
{
  "b": 1
}
```

But if at the same time you open the Chrome console, you will get something like this:

```
{b: 1}
  a:1
  b:1
```

As you can see, the first line reflects the `obj` state at the moment it was logged, but it's content seems to be updated when you click on it.

There is also a blue info tooltip to the right of the logged object that says: "Value below was evaluated just now", wich confirms that it is a feature, not a bug.

```js
function fn(obj){
    console.log(obj);
    obj.a = 1;
}

fn({b:1});
```

Comment: @JohnLee by the way, in my Chrome there is a blue info tooltip to the right of the logged object that says: "Value below was evaluated just now". So it's definitely a feature, not a bug :)

Answer (score 2):

You are logging the object to console. Whatever you've logged is a reference to the actual object. Since you updated the object, the reference will reflect the latest value.

To test, you can try to log obj.a before setting it's value.

Comment: But when `console.log(obj)` is ran, `obj` is not yet changed?

Comment: As I explained, it's a reference. Once the actual object is updated, the reference in console shows the latest value. Try to put a break-point before updating the value and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

that is because when you check the

> {b:1}

the function already finished.

if you check the obj before the function finished,you will find out;for example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

the obj at the console,when act like {...:...,...:...}

[image]

it is a reference,

when you have checked it ,it show you a snapshot of the obj at that moment.At this time ,the obj always like 
{

...:...

...:...

}

for example:

[image]

actually ,this is the real obj at that moment.

so,when you got time to check the obj ,the function already finished.So,you don't have chance to check the obj at that moment except :

[image]

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

give you another obj to see what happened at that moment.